# Color Value appears to be Logarithmic in 2.92

Tags: color

I've run across a new "feature" wherein the value of a color node appears to be logarithmic rather than linear, as it was in previous versions. This feature does not appear to be affected by the view transform or color space.

[image: color value taken in 2.92]

[image: The same color in 2.91]

I would like to change it back to the linear 2.91 settings, though I haven't found a way to do so.

Comment: That’s funny, the dot slider isn’t moving. That seems like a bug. Any new info as of yet?

Comment: Hello, could you tell us on which color field you have clicked to get this color wheel ? Is it an RGB node ?

Comment: this particular color field is an RGB node, but it appears to be common to all color fields, including viewport display material color.

Comment: I just ran into this as well, when following a tutorial that's using 2.8..really confusing..looks like this is answered in https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/258388/value-in-hsv-not-linear