# What does 18% gray mean in Blender

Tags: lighting, color-management

In photography there is thing called 18% gray, which as far as I have understand is a color on a "gray card", which reflects 18% of the incoming light and when telling the camera to expose to it will somehow calibrate the exposure for you.

However let's say I have a plane with a material in Blender with e.g. a diffuse shader reflecting 18% of incoming light.
And let's say I use standard view transform since filmic apparently does this automatically.
When setting the exposure what value should the gray have to be properly exposed?

Comment: The plane should have a diffuse shader at .18 r,g,b to set 18% reflectance.

Comment: Also related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101481/how-do-i-calibrate-exposure-to-match-a-gray-scale

Comment: Related info  https://blenderartists.org/t/whats-with-the-value-slider-in-the-hsv-tab-of-the-default-color-picker/1360186  (depending on how the different color-grading schemes Blender uses in different circumstances affects grayscale).  There's also one similar here that I saw in the last few months, but I can't find it now.

Comment: Here it is:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/258388/value-in-hsv-not-linear/258402#258402